# Can I use '.JS' that downloaded by Node Package Manager (npm) in Browser directly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, typescript

In general, I want to use some library but not through Node CMD for example :

I want to write TypeScript playground but I don't want to call 'tsc.cmd' from "npm\node_modules", I want to call tsc compiler directly in browser.

Can I use below js directly in browser instead of node.js command prompt and compile any ts text ?

I have these js in node_modules :

- tsc.js
- typescript.js
- typescriptServices.js
- tsserver.js

Or

I installed 'beautify' package into Node but in 'node_modules' I have beautify.js

Can I use this js file directly in browser instead of 'beautify.cmd'

Or

...

In General, for some performance reasons I need to call functionality that provided by node cmd directly in browsers

Can I use All JavaScript of Node Packages (node_modules) directly in browser ?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground there is one playground :)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the packages are trying their best to detect how they are loaded (inside node or inside the browser? using CommonJS or AMD? etc.), but in most cases what you will be looking for is the **Browserify** tool:

http://browserify.org/

It takes node.js-style packages and outputs a browser-ready script, in which all the node-specific `require('module')` calls are handled properly (also allows you to replace some modules with your own browser-ready substitutes if you need).

It's a good idea to have a build process somewhere that will handle the task of converting your source to a browser-side packaged script, so that you don't call the `browserify files.js -o output.js` command manually each time. Consider using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) :)

Answer (score 2):

Recently I came across mention that https://tonicdev.com/  allows you to run Nodejs from a browser with access to install and execute npm modules